# Control 3 conditions on a IF in Postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql

I need to control 3 conditions on a IF incoming from a trigger
IF one of three is null.
Follow code only controls the first value (puntuacions) but no next.

```
create or replace function p_controla() returns trigger as $controla_puntuacions$
begin
IF new.puntuacio or new.contingut or new.data IS NULL
THEN
RAISE 'ONE of the columns is empty';
ELSE
RAISE ' ITS OK! ';
END IF;
END;
$controla_puntuacions$ language plpgsql;

create trigger controla_puntuacions
before insert on puntuacions
for each row execute procedure p_controla();
```

Comment: You might want to check the documentation on [Raise](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/plpgsql-errors-and-messages.html). As currently coded you effectively have coded "Raise Exception" and your transaction terminates abnormally. Further, as a learning exercise a trigger for this might be ok, but a better design would be define the columns a "not null".  That makes the trigger unnecessary. Triggers should be avoided whenever possible.

Answer (score 2):

IS NULL has a higher precedence than OR: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-PRECEDENCE

So your IF statement works like this:

```
IF new.puntuacio or new.contingut or (new.data IS NULL)
```

Correct IF statement:

```
IF new.puntuacio IS NULL or new.contingut IS NULL or new.data IS NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

try to test concatenate them , if any of them is null the result would be null:

```
create or replace function p_controla() returns trigger as $controla_puntuacions$
begin
IF (new.puntuacio::text || new.contingut::text || new.data::text) IS NULL
THEN
RAISE 'ONE of the columns is empty';
ELSE
RAISE ' ITS OK! ';
END IF;
END;
$controla_puntuacions$ language plpgsql;
```

Comment: Depending on the data types, this might fail. For example: SELECT NULL::int || NULL::json;

Comment: @FrankHeikens good point , so casting them to text